# Selection and MenuDetection Creating Pop-Up Menu from TrayIcon Differently (OSX)

Tags: java, menu, swt, selection, trayicon

I am developing an OSX application using SWT and I have a TrayIcon in the system tray. I got it to work, but there is this one little thing that really bugs me. When you right click the icon, the context menu is displayed just how I intended.

[image]

(right click)

When I left click, however, it just makes the menu pop-up.

[image]

(left click)

How can I make the left click behave like the right?

The code for both are the pretty much the same:

```
    item.addListener (SWT.Selection, new Listener () {
        public void handleEvent (Event event) {
            menu.setVisible(true);
        }
    });

    item.addListener (SWT.MenuDetect, new Listener () {
        public void handleEvent (Event event) {
            menu.setVisible (true);
        }
    });
```

In case anyone wants to see the code for the whole project:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Event;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Listener;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Menu;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.MenuItem;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tray;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TrayItem;
import org.eclipse.wb.swt.SWTResourceManager;

public class Icon {


public static void main(String[] args) {
Display display = new Display ();
Shell shell = new Shell (display);
shell.setVisible(false);


final Tray tray = display.getSystemTray ();
if (tray == null) {
    System.out.println ("The system tray is not available");
} else {
    final TrayItem item = new TrayItem (tray, SWT.NONE);
    item.setToolTipText("Test Tool Tip");

    final Menu menu = new Menu (shell, SWT.POP_UP);

    MenuItem mi = new MenuItem (menu, SWT.PUSH);
    mi.setText ("View Messages");
    mi.addListener (SWT.Selection, new Listener () {
        public void handleEvent (Event event) {
            System.out.println("Messages will be displayed.");
        }
    });


    new MenuItem(menu, SWT.SEPARATOR);

    MenuItem mi1 = new MenuItem (menu, SWT.PUSH);
    mi1.setText ("Help");
    mi1.addListener (SWT.Selection, new Listener () {
        public void handleEvent (Event event) {
            System.out.println("Help will be displayed.");
        }
    });

    MenuItem mi2 = new MenuItem (menu, SWT.PUSH);
    mi2.setText ("Version 1.0");

    item.addListener (SWT.DefaultSelection, new Listener () {
        public void handleEvent (Event event) {
            menu.setVisible (true);
        }
    });


    item.addListener (SWT.Selection, new Listener () {
        public void handleEvent (Event event) {
            menu.setVisible(true);
        }
    });

    item.addListener (SWT.MenuDetect, new Listener () {
        public void handleEvent (Event event) {
            menu.setVisible (true);
        }
    });
    item.setImage(SWTResourceManager.getImage(Icon.class, "/main/black.png"));
}

while (!shell.isDisposed ()) {
    if (!display.readAndDispatch ()) display.sleep ();
}
display.dispose ();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you add only this( and remove SWT.DefaultSelection and SWT.Selection part) , this will work fine as expected

```
item.addListener (SWT.MenuDetect, new Listener () {

                                @Override
                                public void handleEvent(
                                        org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Event event) {
                                    menu.setVisible (true);



                                }
                            });
```